# HEAD request on firefox returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, axios, fetch, amazon-cloudfront

I need to obtain the size in MB of an image stored in S3 using its cloudfront url. To do this I'm making a HEAD request to use the "Content-Length" as the filesize.

```
axios({
    method: "HEAD",
    url: cloudfrontUrl
})
  .then(res => {
    let mediaSize = res.headers["content-length"] || res.headers["Content-Length"] || 0;
    if (mediaSize > 0) {
        mediaSize = (mediaSize / Math.pow(1024, 2)).toFixed(2);
    }
    resolve(mediaSize);
  })
  .catch(err => reject(err));
```

This works on Chrome but when it comes to Firefox the `res` object is `undefined`. I know it's not some configuration in S3 and cloudfront because this is working on Chrome. Why doesn't it work on Firefox?

I also tried with fetch

Comment: Anything appearing the network tab.?

Comment: In the network tab the HEAD request appears with status 200, and I see the all the response headers including `content-length`

Comment: So if you put `console.log(res)` inside the `then`, your getting null?

Comment: A logpoint in that line returns `res is not defined`, in chrome a console log returns the json response formatted by axios.

Comment: Doing `.then(res => { console.log(res)`  cannot return res is not defined, we are missing something here.

Comment: I know it's odd, trying to create a minimal sample to reproduce